# How to set default parameters to functions in Solidity

Tags: solidity

I came across below example from the [`Solidity Documentation`](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/control-structures.html#function-calls) and have similar code in my project and want to set `default value` to key parameter if the key is not passed from the caller

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract C {
    function f(uint key, uint value) public {
        // ...
    }

    function g() public {
        // named arguments
        f({value: 2, key: 3});
    }
}
```

My questions are -

- Do Solidity language provides `default parameters`?
- How to achieve the same if default parameters are not allowed then?

Appreciate the help?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Solidity does not support default parameters, but it is on their roadmap (see https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/232). To work around this, just use function overloading:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract C {
    function f(uint key, uint value) public {
        // ...
    }

    function h(uint value) public {
        f(123, value);
    }

    function g() public {
        // named arguments
        f({value: 2, key: 3});
    }

    function i() public {
        h({value: 2});
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems worth pointing out that Solidity allows functions with the same name, if they have different argument types. So they could all be called `f(...)`.

Comment: Very true. I have no idea why I used `h()`...especially after mentioning function overloading.

Comment: Thank you Adam and Carver that's a very valid information

Comment: This is briliant... Been wondering about it for a while.

Answer (score 4):

Openzeppelin does a great job exemplifying how you can make "default" arguments. Check out their [SafeMath Library](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol).

In it, they have two sub (subtraction) contracts that are identical visibility and mutability wise- but a key difference:

```
function sub(
    uint256 a,
    uint256 b
)internal pure returns (uint256) {
    return sub(a, b, "SafeMath: subtraction overflow");
}

function sub(
    uint256 a,
    uint256 b,
    string memory errorMessage
) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    require(b <= a, errorMessage);
    uint256 c = a - b;

    return c;
}
```

The first one by default takes two arguments a & b (which will be subtracted). If a third argument is not given (the error statement) it will default to

> SafeMath: subtraction overflow

If a third argument is given, it will replace that error statement.

Essentially:

```
pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.9.0;

contract C {
    function f(unit value) public {
        uint defaultVal = 5;
        f(defaultVal, value);

    function f(uint key, uint value) public {
        // ...
    }

    function g() public {
        // named arguments
        f(2, 3);
    }
}
```

Comment: But, with this solution how I can use both `f` methods from web3? Because I could only use the first method f.

Comment: @HenryPalacios I believe if it doesn't work by calling `f()` with the supplied arguments (2 vs 3) you may need to get the HASH ID name and call the function that way from a web3 perspective.